# Errors in Solution: How to add ignored errors to the team-shared file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, resharper

I have some errors reported by Resharper in ASP code-before files, which are very difficult to avoid (code is perfectly working though). In the "Errors in Solution" - window, I could simply ignore them. Is it possible to propagate the ignored errors to the team-shared file?

Thx for any tips

Update:
See the screenshot for the kind of errors:
[image]

I tried to find them under Resharper -> Options -> Inspection Severity, with no luck. Actually I don't want to disable them globally, especially "Unmatched closing tag" is often handy. Best would be a Resharper - comment, but I have no idea if it is possible to add them in code before. The context-menu of Resharper also doesn't suggest it as it normally does in code behind.

Update 2:
I could add the whole files under Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection Settings -> Edit Items To Skip, and save it to the team-shared file. But I don't like to skip the whole file either.

Comment: What kind of errors do you have? Can you change settings for these errors and decrease their severity (errors => warnings)?

Comment: @Dmitry Osinovskiy: See updates in question...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can suppress the error by adding a suppress comment above the code. Unless it only works for warnings?! hmmm. That would mean the team don't have issues either

Comment: @Stokedout How would that comment look like?

Comment: In visual studio below the line that resharper suggests is an error, click on it and select from the small option menu that appears to the left hand side?

Comment: @Stokedout Exactly, that's what I normally would do, but here it doesn't suggest "Suppress inspection ... with comment" as it usually does. But I am also quite sure that there should be a comment for this type of error, I only don't know the syntax.